# admob ads not show up in real phone,only in emulator

Tags: android, admob

I use admob and millennial media ads.

I am not receiving any millennial media ads probably to low fill rate.(i want to solve the admob problem first).

As for admob ads ,they show up in the emulator (using ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID") but they don't show in real phone.

Also, sometimes i receive a message:

```
An error occurred while loading data in AdWebView:
 E/Ads(280): java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/Ads(280):    at android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(WebView.java:1626)
 E/Ads(280):    at com.google.ads.h.loadDataWithBaseURL(SourceFile:128)
 E/Ads(280):    at com.google.ads.c$c.run(SourceFile:142)
```

and :

```
W/webcore ( 915): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
```

I use the lastest sdks for android and admob.

I also did

> target=android-13  in project.properties file.

I use admob like this:

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView5"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:adUnitId="....."
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"          
                         ads:refreshInterval="30"
```

and in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: When using `ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"`, TEST_DEVICE_ID should be replaced with your actual device id to get test ads on your device.  The SDK will spit out the device Id you should add inside the logs when making a request.  The "error" message is an issue with Android's WebView that was caught and logged by the SDK.  It really should be logged at the warn level, because it doesn't crash the app.  I'm not sure why the webcore warning is logged, but I see it all the time myself, and it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Basically, everything looks correct here.  If you recently created your pub id, know that it may take a few days and multiple requests for that id to start receiving live ads per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/#whynoads).

Comment: @Eric Leichtenschlag:So,to understand.In order to see ads in my device i must use ads:testDevices="mydevice id"?And then , it doesn't matter if i leave this in my code?As for the webview thanks for the info.Thank you!

Comment: @Eric Leichtenschlag:I just tried it but still no ads..

Comment: In order to see `test` ads (which should return 100% of the time) you would need to use `ads:testDevices`.  If you don't do this, you should eventually be seeing some live ads.  Is there any log output that you're seeing from the SDK as to why you aren't getting ads?

Comment: @Eric Leichtenschlag:Hello, it seems to work now.I changed width and height to wrap_content again and i added the device id.Because i have a problem with my device i want to ask you.I got the device id by the millennial media (because i tested it first).This id is the same for admob too?It's unique for the device?And finally,when i publish the app i must remove the ads:testDevices="device_id"?Thanks! (also ,if you want make an answer in  order to accept)

Comment: @Eric Leichtenschlag:Also,i am still receiving the error "An error occurred while loading data in AdWebView:" as i say in my post.I noticed that it appears when i change layout.In my code i don't have anywhere functions onResume or onRestart.I tried to implement them but with no success.I don't know what exactly to insert there.So, i left them and the app runs without them.If the problem is due to that could you please tell me ,or point somewhere,in order to understand what exactly to put in these functions?Because i haven't see any example like that.Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"`, the `TEST_DEVICE_ID` should be replaced with your device id to get test ads on your device.  The id that AdMob uses is a hashed version of your phone's device id though, so you will need to get the value from LogCat (it may be different than the unique device identifier used for millennial).  If you make an ad request on your device, your phone should spit out a log at the info level that says:

```
I/Ads: To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("THIS_WILL_BE_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID");
```

Use the hashed device id provided in order to get test ads on your device.  You can release with this code in there.  All other devices will have a different id, so they will get live ads and not test ads.

The `An error occurred while loading data in AdWebView` error message is a known issue with Android's WebView that was caught and logged by the SDK. It really should be logged at the warn level, because it doesn't crash the app.

Also, I'm not sure why the webcore warning is logged, but I see it all the time myself, and it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: :Ok, thanks for your help.Also,if i remove the ads:testDevices before publishing it's ok,right?

Comment: :And finally, :) , do i need in my code onResume and onRestart methods for the case of changing the layout?Because  i don't use them and the app runs fine (except for the error above).If i do need them could you please point me somewhere because i haven't see any examples in any book about that.Thanks again!

Comment: It is also ok to remove the testDevices portion.  You don't need to put anything AdMob related in onResume or onRestart - I doubt it affects the frequency of that AdWebView warning (remember it's not really an error because it is caught and doesn't crash the app).

Answer (score 1):

**You can try following Code 
in .manifest file you can use**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

**in .xml file file**

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your-package-Name"

<com.google.ads.AdView  android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    ads:adUnitId="674f76af93c2678d"//your application unit Id write here
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

**In .java file write simple code**

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

AdView adv = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
        re.setTesting(true);
        adv.loadAd(re);
```

//==============================

Comment: :Hello, i want to ask you .The java code is necessary?Since i use the xml.Also,in java code the setTesting(true) is only for testing purposes in the emulator and i should not put it in my app?As for the manifest i have it exactly like that.Thanks

Comment: java code is not necessary. you can also use xml,but main thing is unit id that is necessary..

Comment: Beginning in v4.3.1 of the AdMob SDK, you do need the extra configChanges for the AdActivity: `<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`

Comment: @sandeep patel:Hello,i tried it but it doesn't work either.(Also,the setTesting doesn't work in newest versions).

Comment: @George setTesting works for emulators only, and is actually deprecated for the preffered `addTestDevice()/setTestDevices()` methods, or the `testDevices` xml parameter, which is a little bit more intuitive.  All test device methods will only whitelist test ads on devices you specify - it is written this way so even if you release your app with those test devices in there, all other users would still get live ads.